# Understanding how to read error Syntax

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, syntax

I'm trying to understand how to read the numbers in error message, i.e.

```
 ProfileController.js: Unexpected token (**157** : **37**)
```

How do you read the numbers, is the first number the line number or is the second number a line number? What does the other number mean?
I know what unexpected token means I just want to know how to read the numbers to help in future debugging.

Thanks in advance

Comment: it is <line-number>:<column-number>. Column number means the _nth_ character position on <line-number> (zero indexed).

Comment: clicking on it in most debuggers will take you to the line and character.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response Jeffrey.

Comment: Thanks Epascarello I was just using the command prompt thought I don't have much knowledge yet of debuggers besides the dev tool in chrome